# Iconography Sizing - Creating a Grid

Tags: website-design, icon, grids, dimensions

I’m trying to create a grid to make my icons more consistent. At first, I decided to play with 24x24 px as my default size (with 1px line weight). To maintain visual weight, my circles were 22x22 px, my squares were 20x20 px, and my rectangles were 24x16 px... and that generally worked.

However, I want to size down to make 20x20 my default instead of 24x24... but I can’t just use my existing grid and change it, 1-for-1, to 20x20 without getting non-integer dimensions.

I’m also struggling with getting the right proportions within a 20x20 grid. Are there common dimensions for squares, circles, and rectangles that I can use in this case? Is there another way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

Width and height should be even numbers.

Try using an artboard size of any standard size: 16×16; 28×28; 30×30; 40×40; 48×48; 64×64; 96×96; 128×128, etc.

Standardization is key always.